# Query previous rows on a condition

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a table of data about a user's flight booking patterns on a website. Let's assume the following data is all the historical data I have about my user.

The `session_date` is the day that the user came onto the website and searched a specific route, while the `flight_date` is the departure date of the flight. I have ordered the table by the `session_date`. The outcome is recorded in `booked`.

```
+---------+--------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+--------+
| user_id | session_date | departure_code | arrival_code | flight_date | booked |
+---------+--------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+--------+
| user1   | 7 Jan        | CA             | MY           | 8 Mar       |      1 |
| user1   | 8 Jan        | US             | MY           | 18 May      |      0 |
| user1   | 8 Jan        | US             | MY           | 18 May      |      1 |
| user1   | 8 Jan        | CA             | MY           | 19 Mar      |      0 |
| user1   | 9 Jan        | US             | MY           | 18 May      |      1 |
+---------+--------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+--------+
```

I would like to output a new column in my table, called `previous_flight_date`. The new column will state with each search, the previous booked `flight_date` for that specific route. Even if a user has searched that same route multiple times but never booked, the value in this column will be empty.

```
+-------+--------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+--------+----------------------+
|  _id  | session_date | departure_code | arrival_code | flight_date | booked | previous_flight_date |
+-------+--------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+--------+----------------------+
| user1 | 7 Jan        | CA             | SG           | 8 Mar       |      1 | null                 |
| user1 | 8 Jan        | US             | MY           | 18 May      |      0 | null                 |
| user1 | 8 Jan        | US             | MY           | 18 May      |      1 | null                 |
| user1 | 8 Jan        | CA             | SG           | 19 Mar      |      0 | 8 Mar                |
| user1 | 2 Feb        | US             | MY           | 2 Jul       |      1 | 18 May               |
+-------+--------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+--------+----------------------+
```

so for example, the column will be null until the 4th row which reflects '8 Mar', as the user had booked a flight from CA-->SG, to depart on that day.

I have tried using LAST_VALUE but it didn't work. I also do not know how I can use LAG() when I have multiple different types of routes, and I want to find previous rows on a condition. Would be great if a solution was suggested! thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can do this with `first_value()`. The trick is to put a condition within the window function, turn on the `ignore nulls` option, and then use a window frame specifications that looks back on the previous rows having the same departure/arrival, not including the current row:

```
select
    t.*,
    first_value(case when booked = 1 then flight_date end ignore nulls) over(
        partition by departure_code, arrival code
        order by flight_date desc
        rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
    ) previous_flight_date
from mytable t
```

Actually a window `max()` would work too (and then, no need for `ignore nulls`):

```
select
    t.*,
    max(case when booked = 1 then flight_date end) over(
        partition by departure_code, arrival code
        order by flight_date desc
        rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
    ) previous_flight_date
from mytable t
```

Comment: This is a very nice answer, which is beyond my capability, but +1 to you anyway.

Comment: I like the `max()` version better.

Answer (score 2):

I started off going with your suggestion to use `LAG`, but then found it to be rather difficult to phrase a query.  For one approach which does not use analytic functions, we can try just using a correlated subquery to identify the most recent booked flight date on the same route.

```
SELECT user_id, session_date, departure_code, arrival_code, flight_date, booked,
       (SELECT t2.flight_date FROM yourTable t2
        WHERE t2.departure_code = t1.departure_code AND
              t2.arrival_code = t1.arrival_code AND
              t2.booked = 1 AND
              t2.flight_date < t1.flight_date
        ORDER BY t2.flight_date DESC LIMIT 1) AS previous_flight_date
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY flight_date;
```

### Demo

Demo shown for MariaDB, but the same query should actually run on BigQuery without any issues.

Comment: How could I then select the flight_date on the condition that the user had booked? Sorry if I didn't understand your solution immediately

Comment: @awks987 I gave up on `LAG`.  Check my edit for another way to go here (admittedly not the most performant).

Comment: ok thank you! unfortunately BigQuery does not seem to support correlated queries so I might have to find a way to rewrite it into a JOIN. would that be possible?

Comment: Bummer, because you can't really rewrite this using regular joins.  The only other option I can think of would be `LAG`, but I don't know how to do it.  I will leave this answer up to maybe help someone else give you the solution you need here.

Comment: ah shucks. ok I'll leave this to fate then. thanks for your input!

Comment: see my answer for BigQuery :o)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: the problem is with the inequality join, that BQ dodes not support...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I am afraid this BQ limitation rules out the correlated subquery solution... Window functions seem like the most relevant option here. Or maybe work something out with arrays? I don't have a BQ fiddle, which makes it more difficult to test around!

Comment: I have tried @GMB 's answer and it works great. thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The following is a SQL Server based solution using windowing functions. Big Query solution should be similar as windowing functions are standard

```
SELECT
    *
    , Previous_Flight_Date = MAX(CASE booked = 1 THEN flight_date ELSE NULL END ) 
                             OVER (
                                    PARTITION BY user_id, departure_code, arrival_code
                                    ORDER BY flight_date
                                    ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
                             )
FROM historicTable t
```

Comment: thank you for your contribution! I have used window fn just like this in the end. awesome

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT user_id, session_date, departure_code, arrival_code, flight_date, booked,
  MAX(IF(booked = 1, flight_date, NULL)) OVER(previous_flights) AS previous_flight_date
FROM `project.dataset.table` 
WINDOW previous_flights AS (
  PARTITION BY user_id, departure_code, arrival_code 
  ORDER BY flight_date 
  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
)
```

If to apply to sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'user1' AS user_id, DATE '2020-01-07' AS session_date, 'CA' AS departure_code, 'SG' AS arrival_code, DATE '2020-03-08' AS flight_date, 1 AS booked UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user1', '2020-01-08', 'US', 'MY', '2020-05-18', 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user1', '2020-01-08', 'US', 'MY', '2020-05-18', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user1', '2020-01-08', 'CA', 'SG', '2020-03-19', 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user1', '2020-02-09', 'US', 'MY', '2020-07-02', 1
)
SELECT user_id, session_date, departure_code, arrival_code, flight_date, booked,
  MAX(IF(booked = 1, flight_date, NULL)) OVER(previous_flights) AS previous_flight_date
FROM `project.dataset.table` 
WINDOW previous_flights AS (
  PARTITION BY user_id, departure_code, arrival_code 
  ORDER BY flight_date 
  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
)
-- ORDER BY flight_date
```

output is

```
Row user_id session_date    departure_code  arrival_code    flight_date booked  previous_flight_date     
1   user1   2020-01-07      CA              SG              2020-03-08  1       null     
2   user1   2020-01-08      CA              SG              2020-03-19  0       2020-03-08   
3   user1   2020-01-08      US              MY              2020-05-18  0       null     
4   user1   2020-01-08      US              MY              2020-05-18  1       null     
5   user1   2020-02-09      US              MY              2020-07-02  1       2020-05-18
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I have used window fn just like this in the end. awesome